# How do I use URL parameters to change link href on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I would like to change the href value of a link using URL parameters.

Example:

**Default**
`<a id="dlink" href="link-1">LINK</a>`

But, when the user goes something like this https://url.com/?dlink=link-2

It swaps out the link

**New Link** `<a id="dlink" href="link-2">LINK</a>`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get value from url. If you're not using some javascript framework you can create a function for it using jquery.

Please check [Get url parameter jquery Or How to Get Query String Values In js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js) for it.

After that, get element "a" by ID and set the value there.

```
$("#dlink").attr("href", hrefFromParam);
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer to this function to get URL parameters: [Get url parameter jquery Or How to Get Query String Values In js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js)

And with jQuery you can set the `href`attribute of your `<a>`

```
$('#dlink').attr('href', $.urlParam('dlink'));
```